# Could not find overload for 'PathForResource' when playing audio file

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I had a Swift file that worked fine in Xcode6. When I upgraded to Xcode7, I now get an error that prevents the program from compiling. Below is the code snippet that is not working. The error that I receive just states "Could not find overload for 'PathForResource' that accepts the supplied arguments."

```
func playRecord(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    var tag = sender.view!.tag
    let sound:NSURL

    switch tag{

    case 0: // red
    sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("red", ofType: "wav")!)!

    case 1: // blue
        sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("blue", ofType: "wav")!)!

    case 2: // white
    sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("white", ofType: "wav")!)!


    default:
    sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("red", ofType: "wav")!)!

    }
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound)
    } catch _ {
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()


}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, just a comment on the code you have provided: you really ought not to put the calls to `prepareToPlay()` and `play()` outside of the `do` block in the way you have done, because if creating the audio player fails it will try to play something non-existent.

Comment: @TwoStraws so would you suggest wrapping the two calls in a conditional? the condition checks if the audioPlayer has a good value?

Comment: You ought to consider moving `prepareToPlay()` and `play()` directly beneath the `try` line. If the `try` fails execution will jump straight to the `catch` block so there's no risk of the following two lines being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many exclamation marks for Swift 2, because `fileURLWithPath` now returns `NSURL` not `NSURL?`.

Specifically, change this:

```
sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("red", ofType: "wav")!)!
```

To this:

```
sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("red", ofType: "wav")!)
```

…and the problem should go away.